# Turning my Pop!_OS PC into a Kubernetes node, but it's unschedulable

Tags: linux, kubernetes, pop-os

I am running a local three-node Kubernetes cluster on my LAN. The three nodes are my router, my media server, and my PC. The PC runs Pop!_OS but I'm having a hard time getting it set up.

I used `kubeadm` to initiate the cluster and to join the nodes together, and am using the Calico CNI.

The first problem is that I can't seem to permanently disable swap on Pop!_OS, as I can run `sudo swapoff -a` but it becomes re-enabled after rebooting. Normally, this is as simple as removing the entry in `/etc/fstab`, however, there is no swap entry to remove in this case.

My first question is: How do I permanently disable swap on  Pop!_OS?

Now, the Kubelet is in a crash loop until swap is disabled and it's restarted:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

This allows things like the system, Calico, and Nvidia pods to start running:

```
-> % kubectl get pods -A -o wide | grep pop-os
calico-system      calico-node-spxz4                                                 1/1     Running     4 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    10.0.0.235        pop-os      <none>           <none>
calico-system      csi-node-driver-cvw7l                                             2/2     Running     8 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.103   pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            gpu-feature-discovery-8rx9w                                       1/1     Running     4 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.105   pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            gpu-operator-1711318735-node-feature-discovery-worker-mc5xv       1/1     Running     5 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.99    pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            nvidia-container-toolkit-daemonset-tmjt9                          1/1     Running     4 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.106   pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            nvidia-cuda-validator-ndcr4                                       0/1     Completed   0                 19m     <none>            pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            nvidia-dcgm-exporter-th8w4                                        1/1     Running     4 (25h ago)       5d9h    192.168.179.101   pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-66576                              1/1     Running     4 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.102   pop-os      <none>           <none>
default            nvidia-operator-validator-sl5kc                                   1/1     Running     4 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    192.168.179.100   pop-os      <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-proxy-mjncv                                                  1/1     Running     5 (2d12h ago)     5d9h    10.0.0.235        pop-os      <none>           <none>
```

...however, the GPU metrics exporter that I am trying to schedule on that node isn't running:

```
-> % kubectl describe pod nvidia-exporter-pc-5b78bdcd6d-vmtq4
Name:                nvidia-exporter-pc-5b78bdcd6d-vmtq4
Namespace:           default
Priority:            0
Runtime Class Name:  nvidia
Service Account:     default
Node:                <none>
Labels:              app=nvidia-exporter-pc
                     pod-template-hash=5b78bdcd6d
Annotations:         <none>
Status:              Pending
IP:                  
IPs:                 <none>
Controlled By:       ReplicaSet/nvidia-exporter-pc-5b78bdcd6d
Containers:
  nvidia-exporter-pc:
    Image:      utkuozdemir/nvidia_gpu_exporter:1.2.0
    Port:       9835/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:  all
    Mounts:
      /dev/nvidia0 from nvidia0 (rw)
      /dev/nvidiactl from nvidiactl (rw)
      /usr/bin/nvidia-smi from nvidia-smi (rw)
      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so from nvidia-lib (rw)
      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1 from nvidia-lib-1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-khzrv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  nvidiactl:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev/nvidiactl
    HostPathType:  
  nvidia0:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev/nvidia0
    HostPathType:  
  nvidia-smi:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
    HostPathType:  
  nvidia-lib:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so
    HostPathType:  
  nvidia-lib-1:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1
    HostPathType:  
  kube-api-access-khzrv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/hostname=pop-os
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  30s   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable, 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

I suspect this is due to a warning that can be seen in the node description:

```
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      24m                kubelet     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
```

...however, research indicates that this is usually a harmless warning that should be resolved quickly and shouldn't prevent scheduling anything. Below is the full node description:

```
Name:               pop-os
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.ADX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AESNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX2=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512BITALG=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512BW=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512CD=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512DQ=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512F=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512IFMA=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512VBMI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512VBMI2=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512VL=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512VNNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX512VPOPCNTDQ=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.CMPXCHG8=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FLUSH_L1D=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FMA3=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FSRM=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FXSR=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FXSROPT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.GFNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.IA32_ARCH_CAP=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.IBPB=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.LAHF=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MD_CLEAR=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MOVBE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MPX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.OSXSAVE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.PSFD=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SHA=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SPEC_CTRL_SSBD=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.STIBP=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SYSCALL=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SYSEE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VAES=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VMX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VPCLMULQDQ=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.X87=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XGETBV1=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVEC=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVEOPT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVES=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cstate.enabled=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-hardware_multithreading=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.family=6
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.id=167
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.vendor_id=Intel
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-pstate.scaling_governor=powersave
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-pstate.status=active
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-pstate.turbo=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-config.NO_HZ=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-config.NO_HZ_IDLE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-version.full=6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-version.major=6
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-version.minor=8
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-version.revision=0
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/pci-10de.present=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/pci-8086.present=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/storage-nonrotationaldisk=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/system-os_release.ID=pop
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/system-os_release.VERSION_ID=22.04
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/system-os_release.VERSION_ID.major=22
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/system-os_release.VERSION_ID.minor=04
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/usb-ef_043e_9a39.present=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/usb-ef_046d_081b.present=true
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=pop-os
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    nvidia.com/cuda.driver.major=550
                    nvidia.com/cuda.driver.minor=67
                    nvidia.com/cuda.driver.rev=
                    nvidia.com/cuda.runtime.major=12
                    nvidia.com/cuda.runtime.minor=4
                    nvidia.com/gfd.timestamp=1711817271
                    nvidia.com/gpu-driver-upgrade-state=pod-restart-required
                    nvidia.com/gpu.compute.major=8
                    nvidia.com/gpu.compute.minor=6
                    nvidia.com/gpu.count=1
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.container-toolkit=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.dcgm=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.dcgm-exporter=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.device-plugin=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.driver=pre-installed
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.gpu-feature-discovery=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.node-status-exporter=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.deploy.operator-validator=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.family=ampere
                    nvidia.com/gpu.machine=MS-7D09
                    nvidia.com/gpu.memory=10240
                    nvidia.com/gpu.present=true
                    nvidia.com/gpu.product=NVIDIA-GeForce-RTX-3080
                    nvidia.com/gpu.replicas=1
                    nvidia.com/mig.capable=false
                    nvidia.com/mig.strategy=single
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"csi.tigera.io":"pop-os"}
                    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
                    nfd.node.kubernetes.io/feature-labels:
                      cpu-cpuid.ADX,cpu-cpuid.AESNI,cpu-cpuid.AVX,cpu-cpuid.AVX2,cpu-cpuid.AVX512BITALG,cpu-cpuid.AVX512BW,cpu-cpuid.AVX512CD,cpu-cpuid.AVX512DQ...
                    nfd.node.kubernetes.io/worker.version: v0.14.2
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    nvidia.com/gpu-driver-upgrade-enabled: true
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 10.0.0.235/24
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4VXLANTunnelAddr: 192.168.179.64
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 25 Mar 2024 00:16:19 -0700
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      true
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  pop-os
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Sat, 30 Mar 2024 10:12:10 -0700
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:37 -0700   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:37 -0700   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 10:11:30 -0700   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:34 -0700   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 10:11:30 -0700   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:34 -0700   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 10:11:30 -0700   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:34 -0700   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Sat, 30 Mar 2024 10:11:30 -0700   Sat, 30 Mar 2024 09:47:34 -0700   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.0.235
  Hostname:    pop-os
Capacity:
  cpu:                16
  ephemeral-storage:  238222068Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             32777432Ki
  nvidia.com/gpu:     1
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                16
  ephemeral-storage:  219545457506
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             32675032Ki
  nvidia.com/gpu:     1
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 709fbcb158d7dd28973351156441d28c
  System UUID:                43a79490-8c6e-4b1e-ac81-d8bbc1049bdf
  Boot ID:                    5af7fdf9-5d8b-44bd-934a-46d2f0c379e1
  Kernel Version:             6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
  OS Image:                   Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.7.2
  Kubelet Version:            v1.28.8
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.28.8
PodCIDR:                      192.168.2.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     192.168.2.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (9 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                           CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                                           ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  calico-system               calico-node-spxz4                                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  calico-system               csi-node-driver-cvw7l                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     gpu-feature-discovery-8rx9w                                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     gpu-operator-1711318735-node-feature-discovery-worker-mc5xv    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     nvidia-container-toolkit-daemonset-tmjt9                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     nvidia-dcgm-exporter-th8w4                                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-66576                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  default                     nvidia-operator-validator-sl5kc                                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-mjncv                                               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d9h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests  Limits
  --------           --------  ------
  cpu                0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  memory             0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  nvidia.com/gpu     0         0
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                From        Message
  ----     ------                   ----               ----        -------
  Normal   Starting                 24m                kube-proxy  
  Normal   NodeNotSchedulable       24m                kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
  Normal   NodeReady                24m (x2 over 24m)  kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  24m (x3 over 24m)  kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    24m (x3 over 24m)  kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      24m                kubelet     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Warning  Rebooted                 24m (x2 over 24m)  kubelet     Node pop-os has been rebooted, boot id: 5af7fdf9-5d8b-44bd-934a-46d2f0c379e1
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  24m                kubelet     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   Starting                 24m                kubelet     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     24m (x3 over 24m)  kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   Starting                 16m                kubelet     Starting kubelet.
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      16m                kubelet     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  16m                kubelet     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  16m                kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    16m                kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     16m                kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeNotSchedulable       16m                kubelet     Node pop-os status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
```

How can I resolve the unschedulable taint and run the GPU exporter (and other) pods on the PC? I'm very new to Kubernetes so this one is a bit over my head.